# resultset iterating only one time on while loop

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

So im accessing a mySql database in my java code using a `Statement` to execute my query and save the returning `ResultSet` in a `ResultSet` object then using that same `ResultSet` object, i iterate over the rows from the result and simply print out the data for every row.

Here is the code:

```
public class DBConnect {
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unal_grades", "root", "");
            st = conn.createStatement();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

public ArrayList<Semester> getSemesters(){
    try{
        ArrayList<Semester> semesters = new ArrayList<Semester>();
        String query = "Select * from semester";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("semesters");
        while(rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            float average = rs.getFloat("average");
            boolean active = rs.getBoolean("active");

            System.out.println(name+" / "+average+" / "+active);
            Semester semester = new Semester(id, name, average, active);
            semester.setClasses(getClasses(semester));
            semesters.add(semester);
        }
        System.out.println();
        return semesters;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My problem is that in the while loop, the `rs.next()` statement is only returning true on the first iteration. In other words, it only prints the first row of my table in the database when actually having many rows.

> When debugging, if i inspect `rs.next()` before actually running over it, when i actually run over it on the first iteration, it goes into the loop and prints out the second row of my table.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You code does not compile: you haven't initialize the `st` variable.

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning more than one row?

Comment: @ali786 I think, thats what he's saying with the debugging-part of the question. if he inspects `rs.next()` in the debugger, the second row is found.

Comment: @SantiagoAlvarez But are you sure that you dont get an exception in your while block? (I don't think that that is your whole code). I can not imagine why else you shouldnt get all your rows.

Comment: @TagirValeev Thanks i fixed that, but that was an error on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that in the `getClasses()` method i also modify the `rs` variable and so in the while loop the variable is not the same so it returns false.

the solution is to make the `ResultSet rs` variable local in every method.

like this:

```
public class DBConnect {
    private Connection conn;

    public DBConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unal_grades", "root", "");
        }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Semester> getSemesters(){
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ArrayList<Semester> semesters = new ArrayList<Semester>();
            String query = "Select * from semester";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("semesters");
            while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                float average = rs.getFloat("average");
                boolean active = rs.getBoolean("active");

                System.out.println(name+" / "+average+" / "+active);
                Semester semester = new Semester(id, name, average, active);
                semester.setClasses(getClasses(semester));
                semesters.add(semester);
            }
            System.out.println();
            return semesters;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Positive...thats why I got that doubt the sample you have written previously has no logical bug or systactical bug...

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
try{
  String query = "Select * from semester";
  st = con.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(query);
  System.out.println("semesters");

  while(rs.next()){
    int id = rs.getInt("id");
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    float average = rs.getFloat("average");
   boolean active = rs.getBoolean("active");

    System.out.println(name+" / "+average+" / "+active);
}

System.out.println();
} catch(Exception ex){
   System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: @SantiagoAlvarez he added `st = con.createStatement();` (What I think you have in your original code. otherwise your Statement variable wouldnt be initialized)